# Issue selecting Array object at index 0

Tags: javascript

I have an array (currently with 1 item in) and this prints out as follows:

[image]

The console image is the result of console.log(objects) but I need the first item in that array so I am trying to select the object at index 0 but this is not working and is printing in the console as 'undefined' using the following code:

```
var objects = wpd_editor.canvas.getObjects();
console.log(objects[0]);
```

Comment: What does `console.log(objects)` log?

Comment: what? youre showing us a screenshot of the console NOT being empty, yet your question says the console is empty (shows undefined).

Comment: The console image is the result of console.log(objects) but I need the first item in that array - sorry for not being clear

Comment: Please try this : `console.log(objects['u'])`

Comment: Thanks @AlexandruMihai but it still says 'Undefined'

Comment: @AppleTattooGuy, please try this : console.log(objects[u])

Comment: I'm getting ReferenceError: Can't find variable: u on that @AlexandruMihai

Comment: Where exactly is that code that gets the objects? What other code is it around? You need to give people something to work with.

Comment: It's part of Fabric JS using the function getObjects()

Comment: So is the array being populated after you read it and the console is not showing exactly at that point in time? `console.log(JSON.stringify(objects));`

Comment: That brings back [] - objects is being populated because when I log that in the console it shows the full Array - it's just when I try and be specific and select that first item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems likely that you're trying to log the first element of the objects array before its defined.

Try...

```
if (objects.length > 0)
   console.log(objects[0])
```

If nothing is output then it's a timing issue.

Comment: Nothing is outputted - what I don't understand however is why it outputs when I just do console.log(objects)

Comment: @AppleTattooGuy The console log is a dynamic reference to the array. If you add something to the array after calling `console.log()`, it will show up when you expand the object.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer from @shanzilla, you likely need to wait until everything is loaded—including your Fabric.js module and any drawing you may be doing—before trying to check if something exists. Not sure on how you're loading the Fabric.js code or when you're drawing the canvas, but a quick & dirty way to check if this is the issue is to wrap that log in a timeout:

```
setTimeout(function () {
  var objects = wpd_editor.canvas.getObjects();
  console.log(objects[0]);
}, 1000)
```

This is likely not a sustainable solution for you, but it will let you know that, in that one second that you're waiting, some crucial things are happening, specifically the loading and rendering of the page. For a more sustainable solution, something like the following, which uses [Fabric.js's events API](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-2#events) to wait for the canvas to be rendered, would probably work:

```
wpd_editor.canvas.on('after:render', function() {
  var objects = wpd_editor.canvas.getObjects();
  console.log(objects[0]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should bring you closer to the solution:

```
for(var item of objects)
    console.log(item)
```

or

```
for(var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++)
    console.log(objects[i])
// if this one works, you should check if you accessing the array at the right time.
```

Comment: Neither of those do anything i'm afraid

Comment: but console.log(objects) directly outputs any items in it?

Comment: Yes, that outputs as per the screenshot - I need to only select the first item from it though